# How to Fetch SSL Certificate information from a cloudfront distribution on AWS

Tags: linux, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using boto 2.38 and trying to fetch SSL Certificate information for a distribution however, there doesn't seem to be any field in the returned response.

Same information I can get from CLI tools. Wondering why there's nothing in boto.

Any idea?

Thanks,
Ankit

Comment: So, you are saying it works as expected from the CLI tools, but not from boto?  Probably need to show an example of how you are invoking the CLI, and the response, and your boto code, and response... confirming, first, that you are indeed using the same aws access key id for both requests (I've seen people using different credentials than they realized, with the CLI, since it can operate in set-and-forget mode).

Comment: I'm using the same credentials, that's not an issue. is there an example that you can show to fetch the SSL Certificate information using boto?